# How to properly use a switch statement in while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement

I don't think my `switch` statement is doing anything with my code, I'm new to `java` so I'm not sure how to use a `switch` statement in a `while loop`. I'm trying to take each grade/credit entered so I can find the `GPA`, but I added a `System.out.print` for the grades and it says it's worth 0 no matter what gets entered. Please help!

```
package exercises;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class GPA_Calculator {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String greeting = "Hello, this program will calculate your GPA. You will be asked \n"+
            "to enter your letter grade for each class, then you will be asked to enter \n"+
            "the corresponding number of credits for that class. Once all the grades and credits\n"+
            "have been entered, the program will display your GPA.";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,greeting,"Greeting - Introduction",1);

    char gradeEntered;
    String grade = "";
    String creditEntered = "";
    String inputGrade = "";
    String inputCredit = "";
    String enterGradePrompt = "Enter your letter grade (A, B, C, D, F)\n"+
            "Enter Q to display your results\n\n";
    String enterCreditPrompt = "Enter the credit hours for your course (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)\n"+
            "Enter Q to display your results\n\n";

    int points = 0, sum = 0, credits = 0, gradeCount = 0;

    while(!inputGrade.toUpperCase().equals("Q"))
    {
        inputGrade = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,enterGradePrompt,"Enter grade",1);
        gradeEntered = inputGrade.charAt(0);
        grade += inputGrade.toUpperCase()+"\n";

        inputCredit = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,enterCreditPrompt,"Enter grade",1);
        creditEntered += inputCredit+"\n";
        if(inputCredit.toUpperCase().equals("Q"))
            continue;
            credits = Integer.parseInt(inputCredit);
            credits++;

        switch (gradeEntered){
            case 'A':  points = 4;
                break;
            case 'B':  points = 3;
                break;
            case 'C':  points = 2;
                break;
            case 'D':  points = 1;
                break;
            case 'F':  points = 0;
                break;
            }
        sum += gradeEntered;
        gradeCount++;
    }

    // Prevents "Q" from being printed in results
    grade = grade.substring(0,grade.length()-2);
    creditEntered = creditEntered.substring(0,creditEntered.length()-2);

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    double gpa = sum / gradeCount;

    String results = "The courses you entered are:\n\n"+
            "Grade  "+"Hours    \n"+
            grade+" "+creditEntered+"\n"+
            "Resulting in a GPA of "+df.format(gpa)+"\n\n"+
            "This program will now terminate!";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JTextArea(results),
            "results from the Invitation list generator",1);
}
```

}

Comment: This is a 'while' loop, not a 'do-while' loop.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. I edited my code based off some advice below. I made changes now.

Comment: well, you're adding onto gradeEntered, so each loop it'll add on, making the `switch` statement useless. Also, (not sure about this) maybe the `\n` could be affecting the switch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your switch statement is checking the value of `grade`, but your input is stored in `inputGrade`. The former is never reassigned from the empty string, so points never gets incremented.

EDIT: To expand on the comment below:

- the conditional in either a while or do/while loop isn't being checked. You're checking it inside the loop and breaking out, which is fine, as you can just make an infinite loop and let the break terminate it. However, it shouldn't be duplicated in the loop conditional.
- You should do check that condition early. There's no sense in performing anything inside the loop if the user enters 'q' (also, then, you don't have to have the part where you try to strip it afterwards).

Also, you should always try to keep your variables as locally as possible. There's no need to have anything but the aggregators (totalXxx and yyyEntered in this case) outside of the loop. It just makes it confusing for you in this case, as it's masking the source of your problem. When the `switch` statement hits the first time, it checks the empty string. The second time, it checks the first string. When you hit 'q', it breaks, and skips your last input. If these input variables were declared inside the loop, that would be immediately apparent.

Finally, while I'm here, you have an error in your gpa calculation. The points per score should take the weight of credits as a positive, not a negative. Something like:
`sum(grade * credits) / sum(credits)`

I can post fixed code if you want, but since I suspect this is an academic exercise, it would be more beneficial if you came to the solution yourself.

Comment: I changed "grade" to "inputGrade" and it still comes back 0 no matter what is entered. I'm not sure if I used "points" the correct way either.

Comment: Ok, further code review...
* do/while is for when you have a valid state before the loop, and might be invalid after. There is no user input before, so not the case here
* the switch should come after the user input, not before. This makes it always calculate from the previous input, starting with the blank string.
* the while condition is pointless, because you check within the loop and break on 'Q'

Comment: I have to at least use a while or do while loop with a switch statement. So I took out the break on 'Q' and am just using a while loop. I edited my code above, but it's like the switch statement isn't being seen by the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your switch statement is using `grade` which seems to be never written to. It's always `""`.
You get `inputGrade`, but you don't write to `grade` itself.

As it is always "", you always get nothing from your switch

Comment: To add to this, you should make a default case in case nothing is input.

Comment: There are other problems in your code though.
As above person said, you should have default case, because if person doesn't supply valid input, then you never clear "points". I.e. if I typed in 'A' (and switch was working as you wanted), and then typed in 'M', points=4 would be added twice. Once for 'A' and once for 'M'.
Also, you are assuming credit will be numbers or 'Q', which isn't such a good idea. Apart from problems you'll get trying to parse letters that are not Q to numbers, if there is a restriction of up to 6, put it in there.
Your gpa calculation looks wrong to me too.

Comment: Do you recommend using char instead of string?

Comment: I Do recommend char, but this isn't causing the problem. Added another answer in response to your changed code.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending each grade to your gradeEntered

```
gradeEntered += inputGrade.toUpperCase()+"\n"; // at a point this is something like A\nB\nC\nD\nE.... so it will not match anyway
switch (gradeEntered) {
    case "A":  points = 4;
        break;
    case "B":  points = 3;
        break;
    case "C":  points = 2;
        break;
    case "D":  points = 1;
        break;
    case "F":  points = 0;
        break;
    }
```

so most of the times it will not match to any of your cases.

Either you have to have a separate char for grade and use it in the switch or first use switch and then append it to your variable

Comment: I was just using gradeEntered += inputGrade.toUpperCase()+"\n"; to print the user's input in the results to show the grades/credits. I guess I didn't realized it was effecting the switch statement.

Answer (score -1):

You are adding a newline ("\n") to your input, (`inputGrade.toUpperCase()+"\n";`) so none of your cases are valid.
That is, "A" does not equal "A\n"

I think you should not use "gradeEntered" and instead use:

```
switch (inputGrade.toUpperCase())
```

especially since after running the loop more than once, your "gradeEntered" string will start to look like this: "A\nB\nF\nQ\n", which is very far removed from all your cases.

Also, switching on strings is not good practice - it is a newish development in java, and won't be supported by computers running older versions fo java  - though for your own use, if the compiler doesn't complain then it is fine. Still, better to get in the habit of switching on chars or ints, since most other programming languages won't let you switch on strings.

Comment: P.S. you used inputGrade in your while loop, which was a good move, as if you had used gradeEntered you'd have infinite looping

Comment: I was using char in my switch statement, but when it came time to calculating gpa it would say 'A' = 97 like the ascii table and I wasn't sure how to get around that. Also I used "inputGrade.toUpperCase()+"\n";" in my code to get the input to show in my results. I updated my code to show my changes.

Comment: Switching on strings is perfectly fine. The resulting compiled code is backwards compatible to older versions of java.

FWIW, many languages support [pattern matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) on strings, which is what switching on strings is intended to emulate.

Comment: I did not really think about code that was already compiled. My mistake. But I really do not believe that switching is intended to emulate pattern matching on strings - java already has much better pattern matching facilities - it's just the next logical improvement on a standard switch statement to allow strings.